# Query SUM of value from joined table - returns multiplied result

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database, I have the table: `Job`. Each job can contain tasks (one to many) - and the same task can be re-used on multiple jobs. Therefore there is a `Task` table and a `JobTask` (junction table for the many-to-many relationship). There is also the `Payment` table, that records payments received (with a `JobId` column to track which job the payment is related to). Potentially there could be more than one payment attributed to a job.

Using SQL Server 2012, I have a query that returns a brief summary of jobs (total value of the job, total amount received):

```
select j.JobId,
sum(t.Rate) as [TotalOwedP],
sum(p.Amount) as [TotalReceivedP]

from Job j
left outer join Payment p on j.JobId=p.JobId
left outer join JobTask jt on j.JobId=jt.JobId
left outer join Task t on jt.TaskId=t.TaskId

group by j.JobId
```

The problem with this query is that it's returning a much higher amount for "total received" than it should be. There must be something I'm missing here to cause this.

In my test database, I have one job. This job has six tasks assigned to it. It also has one payment assigned to it (£100 - stored as `10000`).

Using the above query on this data, the `TotalReceivedP` column comes to `60000`, not `10000`. It seems to be multiplying the payment amount for each task assigned to the job. Lo and behold, if I add another task to this job (so the number of tasks is now 7), the `TotalReceivedP` column shows `70000`.

There is a definite problem with my query, but I just can't work out what it is. Any keen eyes able to spot it? Seems to be something wrong with the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each separate `JobId`, `SUM(p.Amount)` sums up the same Amount value for every `Task` record related to a `Job` record with this `JobId`. If 6 records are related to a specific `Job`, then `SUM(p.Amount)` will calulate the amount multiplied by 6, if 7 records are related, then the amount is multiplied by 7 and so on.

Since for each *Job* there is only one *Payment* amount, there is no need to perform a sum on *`p.Amount`*. Sth like this will give you the desired result:

```
select j.JobId,
       sum(t.Rate) as [TotalOwedP],
       max(p.Amount) as [TotalReceivedP]

from #Job j
left outer join #Payment p on j.JobId=p.JobId
left outer join #JobTask jt on j.JobId=jt.JobId
left outer join #Task t on jt.TaskId=t.TaskId

group by j.JobId
```

**EDIT:**

Since the platform used is SQL Server a very neat way (IMHO) to get sum aggregates is `CTEs`:

```
;WITH TaskGroup AS (
   SELECT JobId, SUM(Rate) AS [TotalOwedP]
   FROM #Task t
   INNER JOIN #JobTask jt ON t.TaskId = jt.TaskId
   GROUP BY JobId
), PaymentGroup AS (
   SELECT JobId, SUM(Amount) [TotalReceivedP]
   FROM #Payment
   GROUP BY JobId
)
SELECT tg.JobId, tg.TotalOwedP, pg.TotalReceivedP
FROM TaskGroup tg
LEFT JOIN PaymentGroup pg ON tg.JobId = pg.JobId
```

I am only guessing about the tables schema, but the above should give you what you want. The first CTE calculates `Rate` sums per `JobId`, the second CTE `Amount` sums per `JobId`, the final query uses both CTEs to put the results together in a single table.

Comment: This would work great but unfortunately `max(p.Amount)` can't be used as there could be multiple payments assigned to one job. Kind of a pain.

Comment: @Teifi If this is true then which of these payments to you want to sum with your query? All of them, just one? If just one, then which one?

Comment: It should be a sum of all payment amounts with a matching `JobId`. I thought that the `left outer join Payment p on j.JobId=p.JobId` would solve this but apparently not.

Comment: @Teifi Are you using mysql, sqlserver ... ?

Comment: SQL Server. I should have written that in the question - sorry. Question edited.

Comment: @Teifi In this case a completely different approach could be taken. Have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: I ended up using this method. It works well, and I learned about CTEs in the process. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Use a Sub-Select to calculate the SUM:

```
select j.JobId,
sum(t.Rate) as [TotalOwedP],
(SELECT SUM(p.Amount) FROM Payment p WHERE j.JobId=p.JobId) as [TotalReceivedP]
from Job j
left outer join JobTask jt on j.JobId=jt.JobId
left outer join Task t on jt.TaskId=t.TaskId
group by j.JobId
```

Comment: this has potentially very poor performance compared to a JOIN. I think it misses the problem, see my answer...

Comment: If I can't find an optimized method then I'll use this one - but ideally I'd like to keep the query times as short as possible as this potentially could be returning a very high number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your JOIN constraint must not be specific enough so you are getting too many result rows. Probably payments should be joined on Task as well? Impossible to tell unless you post all table schemas.

Comment: I can post the schemas if you want, but it's going to turn into a very verbose question. Would you like me to?

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the query for the TotalOwed from the query for the TotalReceived. The TotalOwed is based on the individual tasks whereas the payment is linked to the job and not the task.

```
--first query
select j.JobId,
sum(t.Rate) as [TotalOwedP]
from Job j
left outer join JobTask jt on j.JobId=jt.JobId
left outer join Task t on jt.TaskId=t.TaskId
group by j.JobId

--second query
select j.JobId,
sum(p.Amount) as [TotalReceivedP]
from Job j
left outer join Payment p on j.JobId=p.JobId
group by j.JobId
```

Comment: This data is being placed straight into a grid so I can't really run them as separate queries :(